# Native Linking errors in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am try to compile my xamarin project today and suddenly i am getting these errors:

> error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _mono_handle_global_vregs. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly
>   linked in.
>   error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _mono_inst_name. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
>   error
>   MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _mono_local_deadce.
>   Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced
>   and native libraries are properly linked in.
>   error MT5210: Native
>   linking failed, undefined symbol: _mono_print_code. Please verify that
>   all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries
>   are properly linked in.
>   error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined
>   symbol: _mono_type_to_regmove. Please verify that all the necessary
>   frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly
>   linked in.
>   error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _type_to_eval_stack_type. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly
>   linked in.
>   error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the
>   build log.

Can any one point me in any direction why these could be happening?

I have a Firebase iOS sdk added to the solution as binding project

Comment: Does it happen if you create a new project from a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Xamarin bug -> [Watch here.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17199)
You should remove from additional mtouch arguments "--gcc_flags -load_all" to be able to build the project.

**Update**

@Kartik, [Here](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=man%3amtouch%281%29) you can find documentation about `mtouch`.

`--gcc_flags` means :

> Add a number of flags directly to the gcc invocation linking the final
>   binary. This can be used to link static code from another static
>   library file (libXXX.a).The darwin linker will remove any code that it
>   does not see directly referenced, add -ObjC to preserve all
>   objective-c segments or **-all_load** to preserve all static libraries.

Comment: It worked but wondering what does that flag mean and what are the consequences of removing it

Comment: I have no gcc flags and still get the error, any thoughts?

Comment: Rick, have you found a solution? I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Im having the same problems. Any ideas? Are you guys also using Azure Mobile services? Ive got a feeling the fb libs in there clash with the fb sdk ones..

Comment: I had this problem because of using Reveal.app lib. It happened only during compiling for device.  What is the version of Xamarin.iOS you use?  `Specified fix was included in Xamarin.iOS 7.2.1.`

Comment: @Alexander could you please help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820454/unable-to-build-xamarin-forms-ios-application-after-admob-update/38820614#38820614

Answer (score 2):

How i solved this: I had to uninstall Google Cloud Messaging and replaced it with Firebase Cloud Messaging and all works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms, for me it was issue in my code. I was using `Java.Lang.Thread.Sleep(1000)` in PCL. Which on compiling was generating error on iOS which definitely was not a compatible code for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set your reference file within the `References` folder, not `Native References` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when try to use Firebase.iOS.Analytics 
it's because the package depends on (firebase.ios.core and firebase.ios.core
i fixed it by adding in AppDelegate:

```
 Firebase.InstanceID.Loader.ForceLoad();
```