# Xamarin.ios app Native linking failed after updating VS 2019

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing xamarin.ios application using Visual studio 2019 on PC which paired with late 2011 Macbook Pro. Today I accidentally updated the Visual studio to `Version 16.5.4`. Which Updated the xamrin.ios to `Version 13.16.0.13(b75deaf)`. After that I can't able to run application. The visual studio tells to update the Xcode to 11.4 Which is currenlty 11.3. In order to do that I need to update the OS to catelina.,which is not provided for the old mac(also I don't want to upgrade).

Apart from this warning these error also thrown by VS.

```
Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz    



Native linking failed, undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.


linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve this issue without updating the Xcode.Is downgrading of VS is possible? Any help is really apprecitated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a older version of Visual-Studio or Xamarin.iOS, you need to contact to the [support team](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/) to request the version you want.

Refer: [install-previous-version-of-visual-studio-for-mac](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/123413/install-previous-version-of-visual-studio-for-mac) and [downgrade-xamarin-ios-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525386/downgrade-xamarin-ios-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Hi Jack. I contacted support team. They said it only possible in Professional edition. I am currently using community edition. So I am still in the dark

Comment: If so, I don't know any workaround so far. I will update you if I find anything.

Comment: No problem! Once you find a solution, you can share here too:).

Comment: I find another thread that you suggested to downgrade xamarin.ios version on VS. How to do that?

Comment: That seems for Xamarin Studio not Visual Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211796/discussion-between-anand-and-jack-hua-msft).

Comment: Bro. Thanks for your answer. i solved it by installing previous xamarin.ios package.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for `Jack Hua - MSFT`'s answer. 
Rather than downgrading visual studio in PC, I downgraded the Xamrin.ios in my mac.
Earlier I used Visual studio `16.5.0` which comes with Xamarin.ios Vesion `13.14.1.39`.
which was overwritten when I updated the VS 2019 to `16.5.4`.

So I downloaded the Xamrin.ios `13.14.1.39` from this site.[Link](https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-13.14.1.39.pkg).Normally to download xamarin.ios package, we need to have account. In this link just replace the version number to directly download the package.After installing the package in mac, I am able to build the App.